# How to Hide 0 Value in Xaml Text Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, printing

I'm coding a XamlPrint. The xaml defines TextBlock everytime something can be printed on paper. Most of the time, if value is null, the binding just returns `EmptyString`, so it is not seen on my print. It's working fine.

But for Price, it calculates a sum of different values:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding ForfaitQuantity}" Width="100" Margin="1126,1110" TextAlignment="Right" />
```

This is an exemple of text block that prints `Price` for type `Forfait`. Sometimes `Forfait` is 0. And in this case, I want it to show `StringEmpty` instead of 0.

How can i do this? Converter? Anything Else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this with text binding:

```
public class ForfaitQuantityConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
         string stringValue = value as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(stringValue) || stringValue.Equals("0"))
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }

        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Value.Equals will cause an exception.

Comment: I change a bit the converter i use (value is string) then cast it and check if the value was "0" work like a charm